# Markov chain - recurrence and transience

Tags: markov-chains

Does a Markov chain with infinitely many recurrent states and infinitely many transient states exist?

I believe it doesn't exists but I'm not sure how can I prove it.

Thanks guys! :D

Comment: Irreducible? $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the discrete-time Markov chain with infinitely many states $i=1,2,\ldots$, such that $P(X_t=i\mid X_{t-1}=i)=1$ when $i$ is odd, and $P(X_t=i+2\mid X_{t-1}=i)=1$ when $i$ is even. Then every odd-indexed state is a recurrent state and every even-indexed state is a transient state.

Comment: Thanks :) What was your thought process about coming up with this example? Any tips on how to approach such questions?

Comment: @Mankochka The simplest example that every state is recurrent is that every state remains unchanged. The simplest example that every state is transcient is a "right-shift", i.e. every state only transits to the next. Now I merely glue the two examples together by interlacing those states from the two chains according to the parities of indices.